# Windows Oracle VM Box - Cent OS7

Tags: centos-7

I have a windows 10 machine, Oracle VM Box Installed. In that, I have installed the CentOS 7.1. I have successfully configured the network and winscp is working, Inside the VM, ping command is working. But "yum upgrade" command reports "network unreachable" and scp command returns "unable to connect port 22 : timed out".

Please suggest me,
Raja K

**Update / Fixed :**  I have done port forwarding in the VM box host settings as well as disabled the firewall inside the centOS 7. Please check your proxy do.

Comment: Sugestions: Allow VBox in Windows Firewall. Check the DNS settings. Ping Windows side IP and any website like Google.com.

Comment: Don't add the answer in your question. Write a separate answer will full details. It will be helpful to others as well.